# Qt setPixmap() not working with setGeometry() on the fly

Tags: c++, qt

I am implementing something like a small label to show image detail which goes with the mouse. I finished the mouse move event signals and zoom in image processing with opencv.

slots which receiving mouse move event and update the label position and image data.

```
void CameraView::updateMouseCurcor()
{
    if(superres_mode)
    {
        label_x=ui->frameLabel->getMouseCursorPos().x();
        label_y=ui->frameLabel->getMouseCursorPos().y();

// opencv based function to produce the zoom in detailed image src
        toyFuncion(input,output);  

        label_x+=ui->label->width();
        ui->label_3->setGeometry(label_x,label_y,WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        smallPic = QImage((const unsigned char*)(output.data),output.cols,output.rows,output.cols*output.channels(),QImage::Format_RGB888);
        ui->label_3->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(smallPic));
    }
}
```

The problem is, the small label with images doesn't show up.

if I comment out `label_3->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(smallPic));` I could see my label texts goes with my mouse correctly.
[image]

I have debug and check that the small image data is completely OK. I try to show it up in another label just beside `ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(smallPic));`
[image]

if I comment out `label_3->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(smallPic));` and set the label just in the constructor like:

```
cv::Mat temp;
    cv::resize(src,temp,cv::Size(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT));
    smallPic = QImage((const unsigned char*)(temp.data),temp.cols,temp.rows,temp.cols*temp.channels(),QImage::Format_RGB888);

    ui->label_3->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(smallPic));

    ui->label_3->setScaledContents(true);
```

the image show up and moves nice with my mouse.
[image]

I am wondering what's going wrong with my implementation, how the control layers of labels and how the update the label geometry and images at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies here

```
ui->label_3->setGeometry(label_x,label_y,WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
```

Instead of WINDOW_WIDTH and WINDOW_HEIGHT try to give width and height of image. Set geomtery after setting up pixmap of the label.

Comment: WINDOW_WIDTH and WINDOW_HEIGHT is #define values(not shown here), I have try to set them to special int like 100, 80, and set geometry after set up pixmap. and it's not working out.

Comment: try to give width and height of image instead of 100,80.

Comment: width and height of the image is exactly WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT, I make opencv mat of this size.